# Fixed Point of $x_{n+1}=i^{x_n}$

Tags: complex-numbers, tetration, power-towers

For $x \in \Bbb C$, let $f(x)=i^x = \exp(i\pi x)$, where $i^2=-1$. Then find the fixed points for $f$.

**EDIT:** Let for all $n\geq 1$ $$\large a_n=\underbrace{i^{i^{\cdots i}}}_{\text{$n$ times}}$$

My question is, does the sequence of tetrations $\{a_n\}_{n\geq1}$ converge to some complex number? If yes, then what is it?

Comment: How do you define $i^x$ for $x$ in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Sorry @Did for not answering before. I define $i^x$ in $\mathbb{C}$ as $i^x=\exp(i\pi (Re(x)+iIm(x))=\exp(-Im(x))e^{(i\pi Re(x)))}$

Comment: There are several mistakes in the formula you suggest. Once they will be corrected, you could try to solve the system $\Re(i^x)=\Re(x)$, $\Im(i^x)=\Im(x)$ and see what happens.

Comment: Oops! The edit brings a different question to the fore... Samrat: please do not do that; instead, try to focus on some well-defined question and ask just this question (not several badly defined ones).

Comment: @Did I had this question in mind that whether infinite tetration can converge to some point. Maybe I have not correctly represented that problem. Could you just put some light what the correct question should be?

Comment: It seems that you are in fact interested in the function $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $F(x,y)=(\cos(x\pi/2)\mathrm e^{-y\pi/2},\sin(x\pi/2)\mathrm e^{-y\pi/2})$ and that you are asking for the asymptotics of the sequence $(x_n,y_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ defined by $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})=F(x_n,y_n)$ for some given $(x_0,y_0)$. Not sure even *that* makes for a good question though...

Comment: @Did I worked a little on my question and I actually found this function to be the one giving the points $(x,y)$ to which the tetration converges(if). I think, from the continuity and monotonicity of this function and due to its boundedness, there is exactly one fixed point $(x,y)$ for this function and if the tetration I'm asking for converges, it converges to this point. Well, maybe my question was not a good one, but I was curious to know it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: OK. (But $F$ is not bounded.)

Comment: @Did Oh, yes, my bad, $F(x,y)$ is not bounded. I was just thinking for $\mathbb{R^+}\times \mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: Fortunately, $F(K)\subset K$, where $K=[0,1]^2$ is bounded.

Answer (score 6):

We had this question quite recently, as I recall.  But I cannot now find it.  Anyway, here we see $a_n$ for $n$ from $1$ to $50$.  They are converging, right?

[image]

The limit is:
$$
\frac{2i}{\pi}W\left(\frac{-i\pi}{2}\right) \approx .4382829366+.3605924718 i
$$
Of course $W$ is the Lambert W function.